# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_AspNetUsers' in a Blazor server-side app

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I know this question has been asked many times, but all of the answers I've seen seem to relate to the entity in question coming from a different context from the current one, such as client/server scenarios like ASP.NET MVC.

In my case, that's not true, as all the action is happening in one code block. It's all in a Blazor server-side app if that makes any difference.

I'm using ASP.NET Identity, with the Identity model named `User`. I have a `History` model (irrelevant properties removed for clarity)...

```cs
public class History {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string UserID { get; set; }
  [ForeignKey(nameof(UserID))]
  public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to create a new `History` item as follows...

```cs
string email = (await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync())
  .User.Identity.Name.ToLower();
User user = await Context.Users.SingleAsync(u => u.Email.ToLower() == email);
History h = new() {
  // Other properties removed for clarity
  UserID = user.Id,
};
Context.Histories.Add(h);
await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

...but this is throwing an exception...

*Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_AspNetUsers'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.AspNetUsers'. The duplicate key value is...*

As you can see, all of the code is happening in the one block, so both the `User` entity that is retrieved from the database, and the newly-created `History` enity that I'm trying to save should be in the same context. I can't see why it's trying to add a new `User`.

The context is injected into the Blazor component in the regular way...

```cs
[Inject]
private ApplicationDbContext Context { get; set; }
```

...and is set up in `Startup.cs` as follows...

```cs
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => {
  options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
  options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
  options.EnableDetailedErrors();
}, ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

This is a fairly mature app, and doing this sort of thing seems to work fine everywhere else, it's just this new `History` item that's causing an exception, even though we do the same thing elsewhere.

I tried...

- Setting the state of the user to unchanged
- Adding `AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution()` when retrieving the user
- Setting the `User` property rather than the `UserId` property
- Setting the `User` property to `null` before saving

...but none of this helped.

As an experiment, I tried injecting a second context, and using that to get the user Id, then disposing it and setting it to null, just to make sure it wasn't hanging around. At this stage, the original context had never touched the users at all, and I had a plain string with the required Id. However, I still got the same exception.

Anyone any ideas? Thanks

Comment: The above code, in isolation, seems fine to me.  Is that Context being used elsewhere?  Is it freshly injected into the controller?  Can you show the Context registration from Startup?

Comment: @NeilW The context is injected into the component (see my updated question), and is used elsewhere, but only within this component. The code I showed is the only place where users are accessed. I also added the code from `Startup.cs`, but I don't think that will help, as it's bog-standard. Thanks

Comment: I asked about the startup because the obvious most likely cause is the lifetime of the context and other entities being tracked from other pieces of logic.  Even though its transient, it will still be the same instance for the lifetime of the component and if you're using it 'elsewhere' in the component this is the most likely cause.  Either adapt your design to ensure DbContext is short-lived (i.e. for each transaction).  It's rare that you need to call SaveChanges twice on the same context.  Or ... after each place you execute SaveChanges then immediately call Context.ChangeTracker.Clear().

Comment: @NeilW Thanks for the comment, but we almost always have components that call SaveChangesAsync in various places, and we've never had this problem before. As it happens, this is the first (and so far only) time it gets called in this component. Up until now, all the component has done is read data from the context. Not sure where this leaves me. Thanks again, any further ideas?

Comment: @NeilW Please also see the update I just made to the question about an experiment. I really don't understand why this is happening now.

Comment: Well, to debug, just before calling the Save Changes that throws the exception you could enumerate Context.ChangeTracker.Entries and see what the context is holding at that time and what state they're in.  I presume your User class inherits from IdentityUser?  What does your identity registration look like?  Ultimately, your context must be holding a user entity in an 'added' state that is mapped to the AspNetUsers table, when one with that id already exists.

Comment: Lol.  Glad you found it!  PS.  The logging of what was in the change tracker would have got there! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Sigh, it turned out that I was not only barking up the wrong tree, but in the wrong forest!

The problem was nothing to do with the `UserId` property on the `History` item per se, it was one of the omitted (seemingly innocuous) other properties (passed in via a parameter) that had a navigation property that had a reference to a `user`, and that was causing the exception.

I changed the code to ignore the parameter and get the other property directly from the database, and it all works fine now.

Don't know if this will help anyone, but I thought I'd post it as an answer just in case.